# error in zxing api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, zxing

I have downloaded zxing apis from net and included all the 6 needed frameworks, but still I am getting error like:

> - 'AVCaptureDevice' undeclared (first    use in this function).
> - 'AVCaptureTorchModeOn' undeclared    (first use in this function)

Plz guide me how it will solve.

Thanks.

Comment: Which 6 frameworks have you added? Was one of them `AVFoundation`?

Comment: @Archana: Do you mean http://code.google.com/p/zxing/? What exactly did you download, and what code are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `AVFoundation` framework.  If you have already done this, check that it is enabled for the target you are building.